# different cart in different tabs of browser

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I need to treat each tab's cart differently in magento backend. For ex, if a product is added to a customer's cart in one tab and then when I open the same create order page in new tab of browser then the item in cart of first tab should not be accessible in second tab.

I know if we take cart as session then this is not possible as session remains same in multiple tabs, but if we consider the cart data from `DB.sales_flat_quote` tables, then this could be possible.

So that I can create order of one customer in first tab and then create order of second customer in second tab at same time.

May be this is possible after creating separate quotes in sales_flat_quote table. please share your ideas with me.

Please let me know the ideas of implementing this.

Comment: I think you are looking for the answer in the wrong place. Get your browser (chrome?) to handle seperate sessions. A quick google reveals there may be ways to  do that. Not sure what is current or if at all posdible. Not done this myself. http://superuser.com/questions/218107/is-there-a-chrome-plugin-to-create-separate-session-in-a-tab

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this as far as I know because your session across different browser tabs are the same. Magento uses your session to work with your quote/cart.

The only way this could remotely work that I can think of is to have some kind of unique GET parameter persist through all of your page requests and have that parameter link to a quote in the backend. Seems clunky and annoying at best.

I would just use different browsers. Keep Magento simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although I would not recommend it from a security point of view, you could achieve this if by putting the session_id into the URL instead of using a cookie.

Please keep in mind this makes session hijacking and session fixation attacks easier, so make sure your code handles that. Your code should check if session_id is generated on the server, the system should not accept a session_id it didn't generate. This is to avoid session fixation. Also, validating that the IP address didn't change between the current and the last request should help to prevent session hijacking. You could also take other data from the browser to verify the client/user didn't change.